# Why is this test using Jest & react-test-renderer throwing error because it's trying to parse a .graphql file?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, jestjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to run a simple test to get going with Jest and it seems like it's parsing the whole app. The file where the error is being thrown is referenced by the services file.

If I do not include `graphql` in the regex for `moduleNameMapper` Jest tries to parse the `.graphql` file itself.

When the file `app-container` is being parsed, `graphql.js` from apollo-client is throwing an error trying to parse an imported `.graphql` file.

**Edit:** If I put the queries inline using `gql` those errors stop. Any ideas with using imported queries?

From `package.json`:

```
 "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "transform": {
      "\\.(gql|graphql)$": "jest-transform-graphql",
      ".*": "babel-jest"
    },
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src/modules"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(graphql|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|yml)$": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
    }
  }
```

webpack-config:

```
loaders: [{
            test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
            loader: LOCAL_ENV ? `style!${CSS_LOADERS}` : ExtractTextPlugin.extract(CSS_LOADERS)
        }, {
            test: /\.json$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'json'
        }, {
            test: /\.yml$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'json!yaml'
        }, {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }, {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'url?limit=1000' // 1KB
        }, {
            test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
        }]
```

Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import services from 'app-system/services';

test('Component should render with a Provider', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(
        <Provider store={services.reduxStore}>
            <div>This is a test</div>
        </Provider>
    );

    const tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree.type).toBe('div');
});
```

Error:
     FAIL  src/app/**tests**/store.test.js
      ● Test suite failed to run

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

      at Object.parser (node_modules/react-apollo/lib/parser.js:12:41)
      at graphql (node_modules/react-apollo/lib/graphql.js:74:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/modules/group/components/app-container/index.js:52:52)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/modules/group/components/index.js:1:418)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/modules/team/components/hello/index.js:2:45)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/modules/team/components/index.js:1:378)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/modules/team/index.js:1:209)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/modules/system/register-modals.js:17:57)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/modules/system/services.js:26:49)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/__tests__/store.test.js:4:43)
```

Line 74 from `graphql.js`:

```
var operation = parser_1.parser(document);
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the graphql file extensions from my moduleNameMapper and it worked. For anyone else having a similar issue, take a look at the question above and make yours look like:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|yml)$": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      ...
    }
```